# Trying to fill an empty cell

Tags: excel

I have a table I need a function that check whether a cell is empty, and if he is it writes "x" in the empty cell, if it's not empty it doesn't change it.

Comment: Function? Is this [tag:vba]?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show what you have researched / tried already

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to do with an If statement. I suspect the trouble is how to navigate through all the cells in the table to perform the check. If by table you mean an actual Excel table, and assuming it's called Table1 you could use:

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range   
    If cell.Value = "" Then
      cell.Value = "x"
    End If
Next
```

Otherwise adjust the 'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range' part to make sure it's a range of the cells you need evaluated. And technically since the function isn't returning a value it's called a subroutine (sub for short) in VBA, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you're asking for an excel formula that would change the cell that it is in
That is not possible...
A solution for a subroutine (to run manually) to do, is using VBA
Without VBA, using a simple excel formula, you can have an "x" written in the next cell, or a parallel cell (with the same address) in a different spreadsheet

The simple if formula, assuming cell A1 is the cell checked
In the case where the cell isn't blank, the formula would return the actual cell value:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"x",A1)
```